# How to get the Response Back from the Remote Server using an HttpURLConnection Object?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am trying to send an HTTP POST Request to a remote server using an instance of the `HttpURLConnection` class.  Although, I am able to get a response code and a response message, when I try to write the input stream into a `StringBuffer`, I am not able to actually read any lines.

When I analyzed the packets sent from *WireShark*, I noticed that a full response was being sent from the remote server.  My only guess as to why I am not able to see it in the Java program is because the time in which I try to read from the InputStream is too late.

So, how do I read the immediate, **full** response from the remote server using my `HttpURLConnection` object?  Below is the code that I am using:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
String urlStr = "...";
URL url = null;
try
{
    url = new URL(urlStr); 
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
...
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
    {
         sb.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
...
}...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, never mind.  It turns out that what I was looking for was in the HTTP Respone's header.  So, I got what I needed by looking through its headers.  ::Face Palm::